# Host Site With WAMP Server and Windows 2012 server

Tags: php, wamp, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to host my site in windows server 2012 using WAMP.

I was able to install the WAMP server on windows servers. So far I am able to use the localhost to display the WAMP server configuration page on the local server machine, but am not able to display my site on the local machine.

The files for my personal site are located in the `www` folder of the WAMP server.

Any suggestions for me?

Comment: check ur DOCUMENT_ROOT . use phpinfo() to Display where u spawn in. maybe its a simple error from the php.ini

Comment: Have you named your file index.php and renamed the previous index.php to simething like index_old.php?

Comment: By default DocumentRoot is in www or htdocs folder.

Comment: Is your code in the `\wamp\www` folder or a subfolder i.e. `\wamp\www\site` for example?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is in a subfolder

Comment: Considering your subfolder name is `site`, what do u see when you browse to `http://localhost/site`?

Comment: thanks was able to fix, got the folder resolution wrong